# Do we maximize likelihood or likelihood ratio for ML estimation?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I was reading [link](https://wiki.inf.ed.ac.uk/twiki/pub/CSTR/ListenSemester1_2010_11/sohn_SPL99_statistical_model-based_VAD.pdf). And I rewrite (3), here, in link to simplify notation as follows
$$
\Lambda(X) = \frac{\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S | X)}{\mathcal{L}(X)}
$$
Here $\lambda_S$, variance in presence of speech, is unknown and it needs to be estimated by ML. This helps in evaluating decision rule for any given observation $X$ and comparing against a threshold.

Question: When you estimate $\lambda_S$ do you maximize $\Lambda(X)$ or $\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S | X)$? Please note that denominator has no unknown parameters. Numerator is case "with speech" and denominator is "without speech". In the link, (3) is expressed in terms of $\xi_k$ and it's ML estimate is derived which seem to suggest that they have maximized $\Lambda(X)$. This does not seem to be intuitive or inline with ML estimate definition

Comment: @Xi'an, I didn't understand what was unclear. Title should make it clear - Do we maximize likelihood or likelihood ratio in ML. I was not able to understand this fact from the paper. I am sorry I was not able to avoid the link and make it self-contained. Without its reference it was hard to frame the question itself.

Comment: I suppose the question is clear--but isn't the answer equally clear?  If the denominator doesn't depend on the parameters, then it makes no difference if it's included or not.  That's less a statistical question than it is a mathematical one, if you really want to pursue it.

Answer (score 3):

The numerator is $H_1$, and the denominator is $H_0$, i.e. $P(X|H_1)$ and $P(X|H_0)$. $H_0$ assumption doesn't assume any speech, so we don't have $\lambda_S$. For estimating $\lambda_S$, it doesn't matter if you maximize $\Lambda(X)$ or $P(X|H_1)$ because the denominator is constant with respect to $\lambda_S$. In ML, we solve for

$$\frac{d\Lambda(X)}{d\lambda_S}=\frac{d}{d\lambda_S}\left(\frac{\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S|X)}{\mathcal{L}(X)}\right)=\frac{1}{\mathcal{L}(X)}\frac{d\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S|X)}{d\lambda_S}=0\rightarrow \frac{d\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S|X)}{d\lambda_S}=0$$

which means solving for $ \frac{d\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S|X)}{d\lambda_S}=0$ from the beginning. (Derivations etc. assumes CT case as in your paper).

Comment: Thanks gunes. I understand that if you maximize $\Lambda(X)$ or $\mathcal{L}(\lambda_S | X)$ you will end up with same answer as denominator does not have $\lambda_S$. But what is the right way? What if there was an unknown parameter $\lambda_A$ in the denominator. To estimate $\lambda_A$, do we maximize the ratio or only the denominator?

Comment: If the parameter you'd want to estimate was indeed in the denominator, you'd minimize $\Lambda(X)$ or maximize the denominator. But, since both includes taking the derivative and equating to $0$ as their first step, they'd still be equivalent, i.e. $(a/b)' = ab'/b^2=0\rightarrow b'=0$, when $a$ is constant with respect to our parameter.